# Is there an entity relationship diagram of Django default authentication database models?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

The [Django 2.2 default authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/) uses the [user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model). However it's not clear to me how users are related to [Django 2.2 default permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions) and [Django 2.2 groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#groups). I know that the [permission model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#permission-model) (`Permission (name, content_type, codename)`?) is usually not accessed directly, but I want to understand what's going on under the hood. The [group model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#group-model) seems to be `Group (name, permissions)`. In the docs e.g. the relationship between user.groups and groups is "many". Is it "many optional - many optional", "many mandatory - many mandatory", etc.? The same is unclear for user.user_permissions and permissions.

Is there an entity relationship diagram of the default, means typical default database models in the docs or somewhere else?

EDIT: When creating a plain Django project and a single superuser the SQLite database contains 11 tables (`auth_group`, `auth_group_permissions`, `auth_permission`, `auth_user`, `auth_user_group`, `auth_user_user_permissions`, `django_admin_log`, `django_content_type`, `django_migrations`, `django_session`, `django_sequence`) which is very different from which one would expect from the docs only.

Comment: you can start by going through the source code of [django.contrib.auth.models](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py) on github

Comment: @NalinDobhal I found the models in the docs. I just hoped for a diagram which would svae me the time to go through it...

Answer (score 1):

In the hopes that it may help a future reader of this question, here's an ERD I just sketched for the permissions-relevant tables in Django 3.2.9.

[image: Django Permissions ERD]